# What does slang verb "to sheep-dip" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, slang

I am watching *The Expanse* tv series and have encountered the following dialogue:

> - I need to borrow your spy on Tycho Station.
> - What for?
> - To keep an eye on Fred Johnson. He's over-charging the Mormons for their toilet seats.
> - Well, you can't have him.
> - Why not?
> - It took me five years **to sheep-dip** him in Johnson's outfit, to steal tech for his competitors.

What does the verb *to sheep-dip* mean in the context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.wordnik.com/words/sheep-dip : *The practice within the intelligence community of assigning to agents non-intelligence or military jobs in order to disguise their source agency.*

Ranchers "dip" livestock in solutions designed to kill parasites and keep them healthy.

[image: Sheep getting dipped]

Assigning spies common jobs is a process to "wash" them clean and make it easier for them to infiltrate an organization.